# Android Paint measureText returns length of string?

Tags: android

I have a textPaint view and called measureText(text) to get the pixel length of text.

It works great on my codebase but when I writing the unit test I figured it returns the length(num of chars) of text instead of pixel length... I debugged the codebase and found out it does return the pixel length but only in unit test returns length of char.

Wonder what happened and how can i get the unit test covered this...

Comment: Are you able to post the code from your codebase as well as the unit test?

Comment: Do you use any framework for unit tests?